# Framework to track changes and relationships in C#

Tags: c#, object-oriented, library

Recently, I wanted to see how I might could track state changes to objects, and manage relationships (1 to 1, 1 to N, N to N) between types in C#. This was a really interesting project, and I'm wondering how it might be improved.

### Full code

The full code can be found [here](https://github.com/gjdanis/EntityTracker), which includes a test project.

### Basics: `TrackableEntity`, `EntityManager` and `TrackableProperty`

Everything in my `EntityTracker` project works with `TrackableEntity`, which does what you might think.

```
/// <summary>Base type that supports change tracking </summary>
public abstract class TrackableEntity
{
    public int Id
    {
        get; 
        internal set;
    }

    public bool IsDirty
    {
        get;
        internal set; 
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        IsDirty = false;
    }

    public TrackableEntity()
    {
        EntityManager.Instance.Create(this);
    }

    public void Delete()
    {
        EntityManager.Instance.Delete(this);
    }
}
```

All the `TrackableEntity` objects are stored in a globally accessible repository, `EntityManager`. I'll save discussion of the `Delete` method referenced by `TrackableEntity` for later.

```
/// <summary>
/// Container class to hold TrackableEntity objects
/// </summary>
public class EntityManager
{
    private static EntityManager instance = new EntityManager();
    private int next;
    private Dictionary<int, TrackableEntity> entities;

    private EntityManager()
    {
        entities = new Dictionary<int, TrackableEntity>();
    }

    public static EntityManager Instance
    {
        get { return instance; }
    }

    /// <summary>Adds the TrackableEntity in the container</summary>
    public void Create(TrackableEntity entity)
    {
        entity.Id = next++;
        entities[entity.Id] = entity;
    }

    /// <summary>Gets the TrackableEntity stored at id</summary>
    public TrackableEntity Lookup(int id)
    {
        return entities.ContainsKey(id) ? entities[id] : null;
    }
}
```

To actually track changes to properties in `TrackableEntity`, I created an object to wrap each property which allows me to manage the state of the `IsDirty` flag. This object actually holds all values for a type that declares a `TrackableProperty` and looks up the owner's value by id.

```
/// <summary>Wrapper property to track changes</summary>
public class TrackableProperty<T> where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    Dictionary<int, T> values = new Dictionary<int, T>();

    /// <summary>Gets the owner's value</summary>
    public T GetValue(TrackableEntity owner)
    {
        return values.ContainsKey(owner.Id) ?
            values[owner.Id] : default(T);
    }

    /// <summary>Sets the owner's value</summary>
    public void SetValue(TrackableEntity owner, T value)
    {
        if (values.ContainsKey(owner.Id) && values[owner.Id].Equals(value))
            return;
        owner.IsDirty = true; values[owner.Id] = value;
    }
}
```

Here's a simple example of how `TrackableEntity` and `TrackableProperty` are used:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("Name = {Name}")]
abstract class NamedEntity : RelationshipEntity
{
    public static readonly TrackableProperty<string> NameProperty
        = new TrackableProperty<string>();

    public string Name
    {
        get { return NameProperty.GetValue(this); }
        set { NameProperty.SetValue(this, value); }
    }
}
```

### Relationships

The three relationships (1 to 1, 1 to N, and N to N) I support all implement the following generic interface.

```
/// <summary>Base type for relationships between RelationshipEntity objects</summary>
public interface IRelationship<T1, T2>
    where T1 : RelationshipEntity
    where T2 : RelationshipEntity
{
    void CreateRelationship(T1 t1, T2 t2);
    void DeleteRelationship(RelationshipEntity entity);
}

/// <summary>Base type for relationships between TrackableEntity objects </summary>
public abstract class RelationshipEntity : TrackableEntity
{
    public abstract void Accept(IRelationshipVisitor visitor);
}
```

#### Implementation of  `Relationship1To1`

The efficiency of navigating in the reverse direction (i.e. getting `T1` from `T2`) could be improved. For now, however, I'm just using a linear search to make sure the relationship is maintained.

```
    /// <summary>Represents a 1 to 1 relationship</summary>
public class Relationship1To1<T1, T2> : IRelationship<T1, T2>
    where T1 : RelationshipEntity
    where T2 : RelationshipEntity
{
    Dictionary<int, int> forward = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the relationship; t1 and t2
    /// may only reference one another
    /// </summary>
    public void CreateRelationship(T1 t1, T2 t2)
    {
        DeleteRelationship(t1);
        DeleteRelationship(t2);
        forward[t1.Id] = t2.Id;
    }

    public void DeleteRelationship(RelationshipEntity entity)
    {
        var kvps = forward.Where(kvp =>
            kvp.Key == entity.Id || kvp.Value == entity.Id);

        foreach (var item in kvps.ToList())
            forward.Remove(item.Key);
    }

    public T2 GetForward(T1 owner)
    {
        return forward.ContainsKey(owner.Id) ?
            (T2)EntityManager.Instance.Lookup(forward[owner.Id]) : null;
    }

    public T1 GetReverse(T2 owner)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> kvp in forward)
            if (kvp.Value == owner.Id)
                return (T1)EntityManager.Instance.Lookup(kvp.Key);
        return null;
    }
}
```

#### Implementation of `Relationship1ToN`

This seemed pretty straightforward. I use a dictionary to ensure that each child has only one parent.

```
/// <summary>Represents a 1 to N relationship</summary>
public class Relationship1ToN<T1, T2> : IRelationship<T1, T2>
    where T1 : RelationshipEntity
    where T2 : RelationshipEntity
{
    Dictionary<int, T1> children = new Dictionary<int, T1>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the relationship; t2 may only have one owner, t1
    /// </summary>
    public void CreateRelationship(T1 t1, T2 t2)
    {
        children[t2.Id] = t1;
    }

    public void DeleteRelationship(RelationshipEntity entity)
    {
        var kvps = children.Where(x => x.Key == entity.Id || x.Value.Id == entity.Id);

        foreach (var item in kvps.ToList())
            children.Remove(item.Key);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T2> GetFoward(T1 parent)
    {
        return children.Where(pair => pair.Value.Id == parent.Id)
            .Select(pair => (T2)EntityManager.Instance.Lookup(pair.Key));
    }

    public T1 GetReverse(T2 owner)
    {
        return children.ContainsKey(owner.Id) ?
            children[owner.Id] : null;
    }
}
```

#### Implementation of `RelationshipNToN`

This seemed most straightforward. Anyone can own anyone:

```
/// <summary>Represents an N to N relationship</summary>
public class RelationshipNToN<T1, T2> : IRelationship<T1, T2>
    where T1 : RelationshipEntity
    where T2 : RelationshipEntity
{
    Dictionary<int, HashSet<int>> forward = new Dictionary<int, HashSet<int>>();
    Dictionary<int, HashSet<int>> reverse = new Dictionary<int, HashSet<int>>();

    /// <summary>Creates the relationship</summary>
    public void CreateRelationship(T1 t1, T2 t2)
    {
        if (!forward.ContainsKey(t1.Id)) forward[t1.Id] = new HashSet<int>();
        if (!reverse.ContainsKey(t2.Id)) reverse[t2.Id] = new HashSet<int>();

        forward[t1.Id].Add(t2.Id);
        reverse[t2.Id].Add(t1.Id);
    }

    public void DeleteRelationship(RelationshipEntity entity)
    {
        var kvps = forward.Where(x => x.Key == entity.Id || x.Value.Contains(entity.Id))
            .Union(reverse.Where(x => x.Key == entity.Id || x.Value.Contains(entity.Id)));

        foreach (var kvp in kvps.ToList())
        {
            reverse.Remove(kvp.Key);
            forward.Remove(kvp.Key);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<T2> GetForward(T1 owner)
    {
        return forward.ContainsKey(owner.Id) ?
            from key in forward[owner.Id] 
            select (T2)EntityManager.Instance.Lookup(key) : Enumerable.Empty<T2>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T1> GetReverse(T2 owner)
    {
        return reverse.ContainsKey(owner.Id) ?
            from key in reverse[owner.Id] 
            select (T1)EntityManager.Instance.Lookup(key) : Enumerable.Empty<T1>();
    }
}
```

### Deleting relationships

If we delete an `TrackableEntity`, we need to remove all references to it. To me, it seemed that the best way to visit all relationships in the object graph was with the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). At each relationship, we call  implementation of `DeleteRelationship` for the entity to be deleted.

`RelationshipEntity` must be able to accept an `IRelationshipVisitor`. Since we have three implementations of `IRelationship`, we should provide three ways to visit.

```
/// <summary>Base type for visiting relationships in the object graph</summary>
public interface IRelationshipVisitor
{
    void Visit<T1, T2>(Relationship1To1<T1, T2> relationship)
        where T1 : RelationshipEntity
        where T2 : RelationshipEntity;

    void Visit<T1, T2>(Relationship1ToN<T1, T2> relationship)
        where T1 : RelationshipEntity
        where T2 : RelationshipEntity;

    void Visit<T1, T2>(RelationshipNToN<T1, T2> relationship)
        where T1 : RelationshipEntity
        where T2 : RelationshipEntity;
}
```

The visitor for deletion is `RelationshipBreaker` (omitted here for brevity). To delete in the `EntityManager`, all we have to do is visit the relationships and then delete the entity.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Deletes the TrackableEntity from the container
    /// and removes all references from relationships 
    /// </summary>
    public void Delete(TrackableEntity entity) 
    {
        if (entity is RelationshipEntity)
        {
            var casted = (RelationshipEntity)entity;
            casted.Accept(new RelationshipBreaker(casted));
        }
        entities.Remove(entity.Id);
    }
```

### Example code

Here are some examples of entities with relationships

```
class A : NamedEntity
{
    public static readonly Relationship1To1<A, B> relationship
        = new Relationship1To1<A, B>();

    public B B
    {
        get { return relationship.GetForward(this); }
        set { relationship.CreateRelationship(this, value); }
    }

    public C Parent
    {
        get { return C.relationship.GetReverse(this); }
    }

    public override void Accept(IRelationshipVisitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.Visit<A, B>(A.relationship);
        visitor.Visit<C, A>(C.relationship);
    }
}

class B : NamedEntity
{
    public A A
    {
        get { return A.relationship.GetReverse(this); }
        set { A.relationship.CreateRelationship(value, this); }
    }

    public override void Accept(IRelationshipVisitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.Visit<A, B>(A.relationship);
    }
}

class C : NamedEntity
{
    public static readonly Relationship1ToN<C, A> relationship
        = new Relationship1ToN<C, A>();

    public IEnumerable<A> Children
    {
        get { return relationship.GetFoward(this); }
    }

    // how to avoid this -- would like for the relationship to return
    // a custom collection (this has add/remove etc) that enforces the relationship
    public void Add(A item)
    {
        relationship.CreateRelationship(this, item);
    }

    public override void Accept(IRelationshipVisitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.Visit<C, A>(relationship);
    }
}
```

### Questions and points to review

- In the implementation of `Delete`, I cast to a relationship type. I had tried providing two implementations of `Delete`; one for the `TrackableEntity` (no relationships) and another for `RelationshipEntity`. This didn't work, however (the delete call for a test entity kept going through the `TrackableEntity` overload and not to the `RelationshipEntity` overload). Why is this?
- I expose the children of a `Relationship1ToN` as an `IEnumerable<T2>`. As a result, I have to provide additional methods to add an item to this relationship that are exposed in the entity classes. Is there any way to abstract this? Maybe instead of returning an `IEnumerable<T2>`, would it be possible to return an `ICollection<T2>`, and provide checks to maintain the relationship?
- General design -- how did I do?

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: My mistake -- I had thought putting code in a separate section (indeed, not in any of the code I've asked be reviewed) might be okay.

Comment: I always find tracking systems too heavy, and yet not rich and flexible enough. There is a reason Microsoft has given up on SelfTrackingEntities. Your attempt is very nice one. It does not smell like boiler-plate code. Well done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**General**

If you need to get a value of a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` you shouldn't us `ContainsKey()` together with the `Item` property getter but `TryGetValue()`, because by using `ContainsKey()` in combination with the `Item` getter you are doing the check if the key exists twice.

See also: [what-is-more-efficient-dictionary-trygetvalue-or-containskeyitem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382681/what-is-more-efficient-dictionary-trygetvalue-or-containskeyitem)

**TrackableEntity**

This abstract class seems almost fine to me. The only missing is the lack of documentation. A framework should always have enough documentation targeting the the parts which are accesible from outside. So each `public` and `protected` property/method should be documentated.

While we talk about scope, an `abstract` class only serves one purpose, it is intended to be implemented. By making a setter of a property `internal` one who wants to implement such a class can't set these properties (if it is allowed to set them).

If I would implement the abstract `TrackableEntity` class, I would maybe want to set the `IsDirty` property to a specific value, but because its internal I just can't. So making properties which you feel should be set from outside `protected` would be a good decision.

---

**EntityManager singleton**

Hmmm, a singletone is coming along. How am I be able to write unit tests for a singleton or for classes which uses this singleton? Hmmm, I just can't easily do this, because I can't reset the state of this singleton between tests which is bad.

For instance assume we want to test the creation of a `TrackableEntity` object and because it comes handy we assert that `TrackableEntity.Id == 1` so, no problem there, the test passes.

Next we write another test which test for `TrackableEntity.Delete()` and we assert with `EntityManager.Instance.Lookup(TrackableEntity.Id) == null)`.

Then you run both tests and they passed and you ask yourself hey what is this guy talking about but then you change the order of the tests and hence the first written test fails because after the test for `Delete` the `private int next` of the `EntityManager` is `1`. So if the creation test is executed the assert will fail.

What are possible ways out of this ? You can let `EntityManager` implement an interface `IEntityManager` having `Create()`, Lookup()`and`Delete()`methods and use a private field in`TrackableEntity`which is holding a reference of`IEntityManager` which is constructor injected.

The changes you would need to do are simple, some thing along these lines

```
public interface IEntityManager
{
    TrackableEntity Lookup(int id);
    void Create(TrackableEntity entity);

    void Delete(TrackableEntity entity);
}
```

```
public class EntityManager : IEntityManager
{
    private static IEntityManager instance = new EntityManager();
    private int next;
    private Dictionary<int, TrackableEntity> entities;

    private EntityManager()
    {
        entities = new Dictionary<int, TrackableEntity>();
    }

    public static IEntityManager Instance
    {
        get { return instance; }
    }

    /// <summary>Adds the TrackableEntity in the container</summary>
    public void Create(TrackableEntity entity)
    {
        entity.Id = next++;
        entities[entity.Id] = entity;
    }

    /// <summary>Gets the TrackableEntity stored at id</summary>
    public TrackableEntity Lookup(int id)
    {
        TrackableEntity entity;
        entities.TryGetValue(id, out entity);
        
        return entity;
    }

    public void Delete(TrackableEntity entity)
    {
        // we will target this later
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

```
public abstract class TrackableEntity
{
    private readonly IEntityManager manager;
    public TrackableEntity()
    {
        manager = EntityManager.Instance;
        manager.Create(this);
    }
    public TrackableEntity(IEntityManager manager)
    {
        this.manager = manager;
        manager.Create(this);
    }
    public int Id
    {
        get;
        internal set;
    }

    public bool IsDirty
    {
        get;
        internal set;
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        IsDirty = false;
    }

    public void Delete()
    {
        manager.Delete(this);
    }
}
```

Now you use a mocked `IEntityManager` obejct for unit tests.

Another maybe easier aproach would be like described in the answer to [unit-testing-singletons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5897908/2655508)

> Short version: do not write your singletons as singletons. Write them as normal classes, and call them via an Inversion of Control container, where you have configured the class to be a singleton instead.

---

**TrackableProperty**

Using multiple code statements in the same line is hard to read and to debug and should be avoided.

Access to a dictionary should be changed like written above like so

```
/// <summary>Wrapper property to track changes</summary>
public class TrackableProperty<T> where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    Dictionary<int, T> values = new Dictionary<int, T>();

    /// <summary>Gets the owner's value</summary>
    public T GetValue(TrackableEntity owner)
    {
        T foundValue;
        values.TryGetValue(owner.Id, out foundValue);
        return foundValue;
    }

    /// <summary>Sets the owner's value</summary>
    public void SetValue(TrackableEntity owner, T value)
    {
        T foundValue;
        if (values.TryGetValue(owner.Id, out foundValue) && foundValue.Equals(value)
        {
            return;
        }
        owner.IsDirty = true;  
        values[owner.Id] = value;
    }
}
```

---

**Relationship1To1**

- I would make it more clear who the owner of the object is by changing `T1` to `TOwner`.
- Changes to dictionary access should be made like mentioned.

---

**Relationship1ToN**

- Change `T1` to `TParent` to make it more obvious who the parent is.
- Changes to dictionary access should be made like mentioned.

---

**RelationshipNToN**

- Changes to dictionary access should be made like mentioned.

---

**EntityManager.Delete()**

> In the implementation of Delete, I cast to a relationship type. I had tried providing two implementations of Delete; one for the TrackableEntity (no relationships) and another for RelationshipEntity. This didn't work, however (the delete call for a test entity kept going through the TrackableEntity overload and not to the RelationshipEntity overload). Why is this?
>
> ```
> public void Delete(TrackableEntity entity) 
> {
>     if (entity is RelationshipEntity)
>     {
>         var casted = (RelationshipEntity)entity;
>         casted.Accept(new RelationshipBreaker(casted));
>     }
>     entities.Remove(entity.Id);
> }
> ```

To eplain this I will use a simple example like so

```
public abstract class TheAbstractType { }
public class TheInheritingType : TheAbstractType { }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();

        TheInheritingType a = new TheInheritingType ();
        TheAbstractType b = new TheInheritingType ();
       
        p.Delete(a);
        p.Delete(b);
    }
    public void Delete(TheAbstractType item)
    {
        // first
    }
    public void Delete(TheInheritingType item)
    {
        // second
    }
}
```

Calling `p.Delete(a);` will result in the execution of the second `Delete()` because we have declared `a` as `TheInheritingType`.

Calling `p.Delete(b);` will result in the execution of the first `Delete()` because we have declared `b` as `TheAbstractType`.

---

> I expose the children of a `Relationship1ToN` as an `IEnumerable<T2>`. As a result, I have to provide additional methods to add an item to this relationship that are exposed in the entity classes. Is there any way to abstract this? Maybe instead of returning an `IEnumerable<T2>`, would it be possible to return an `ICollection<T2>`, and provide checks to maintain the relationship?

You will be in the same trouble if you are returning an `ICollection<T2>` instead of an `IEnumerable<T2>` because both are only a part of the whole collection (aka `Dictionary`)  of the `Relationship1ToN`.

If you for instance add an `Entity` to this `ICollection<T2>` this won't be reflected in the `Relationship1ToN`.

<s>I would add the relationships as properties to the `RelationshipEntity`'s and would initialize them only when first accessed.</s>

After thinking about it, this idea isn't the brightest one because it breaks the encapsulation of the class. A entity could just mess with the provided relationships of a different entity. IMHO the best way would be to just add the maintaining methods to the `RelationshipEntity` class and keep the relationships as private fields in the class (initializing if accessed too).

If you have the feeling that this would add to much memory overhead you can add a mechanism to let empty relationships expire.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not that concerned about performance, here. As a matter of opinion, would you agree that `ContainsKey` is "good enough" and more readable? [Others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946863/what-is-performance-of-containskey-and-trygetvalue) have remarked that the performance difference is negligible. Also, is there any chance you can offer any advice on one of the points I've asked get reviewed?

Comment: Its not about the performnce difference between `TryGetValue` and `ContainsKey` but  between `TryGetValue` and `ContainsKey()` **together** with accessing the `Item`'s getter.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful answer. I hesitate to mark the `IsDirty` property `protected` because that would mean that `TrackableProperty` can't set it (I want the system to track changes, and not have the entities themselves tracking the changes). I can fix the `EntityManager.Delete()` problem by adding a `Delete` method to `RelationshipEntity` (hide the method). This seems less than ideal -- is there a better way?

Comment: If you're able to review the second point in my "Questions and points to review" section, I will happily reward you the full bounty.